# How to include eloquent appended attributes in JsonResource

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I would like to include appended attributes during construction of my api response in the resource class.

For this i've got a model class called Article.php

```php
class Article extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'articles';

    protected $fillable = ['id', 'articleNo'];
    protected $appends = ['is_available'];

    public function getIsAvailableAttribute() {
        return true;
    }
```

ArticleController.php

```php
public function index() {
    $articles = Article::all();
    return ArticleResource::collection($articles);
}
```

ArticleResource.php

```php
class ArticleResource extends JsonResource
{
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'articleNumber' => $this->articleNo,
            'isAvailable' => $this->is_available,
        ];
    }
}
```

When i try to run my code, it gives me the following error:

> ErrorException (E_NOTICE) Undefined property: stdClass::$is_available

if i remove the line isAvailable from my ArticleResource it works.

Comment: I don't see any code looking for an `in_stock` property. I don't think the problem is anywhere in the code you've posted so far

Comment: Sorry my bad, it's meant to be is_available i just corrected it in the question

Comment: I thinking if you do `return Article::get()` in your `index()` it will return the  all `appends`

Comment: But then it won't go through `ArticleResource`, will it?